# How to add class inside li?

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list and I am using the following code to add class to the current link I visited.

```
$("li a").filter(function(){
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).addClass("selected");
```

The outcome is: `<li><a href="#" class="selected">Link1</a></li>`

But the solution I need is: `<li class="selected"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>`

Please help. Thank you.

Update: Most of the current answers works fine. However, I encountered another problem.

The parent li has submenus. Upon clicking a submenu link, the "selected" class of the parent li is gone. Is there a way to make the "selected" class stays on parent li as well? Or if it's possible to just add the class just on the parent li, and not on any clicked submenu link? Thank you in advance for your help again. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are filtering the anchor element, not the `li` so the `addClass()` will add the class to the `a` element. You can use a ancestor lookup(.parent(), .closest()) to find the desired `li` element and then use `addClass()`

```
$("li a").filter(function () {
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).parent().addClass("selected");
```

Comment: you cannot say it's a direct parent of "a" until you don't know the HTML structure

Comment: @TusharRaj Op has given the html structure

Answer (score 1):

i think this should do it

```
$("li a").filter(function(){
return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).parent('li').addClass("selected");
```

edit

```
$("li a").filter(function(){ return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).parents('li, li:first').addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Hi sir, I posted an update question. Hope you can help me again :)

Comment: ohh sorry you need to change it parent() to parents()

Comment: Thanks sir for your help. Actually the first solution is working. I just overlook some details on my css. It's finally working now. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("li a").filter(function(){
        return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, ""); }).closest('li').addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner and optimized way:

```
var targetUrl = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
var activeNav = $('li a[href="'+ targetUrl +'"]');
if ( activeNav.length ) {
    activeNav.parent('li').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir but it did not achieved the outcome I wanted.